# GE front load washing machine; emptying filter at least once a week

Tags: repair, filter

I have a GE 4.5cu ft front load Energy Star washing machine. I am constantly draining and cleaning the filter/pump. I’ve had this one for a year. The one I had before I had for about 8 years and never had to drain the pump. It frustrating to go and change out clothes and they either aren’t washed or soaking wet still.

Comment: What is clogging the filter??

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Knowing what's being caught in the filter would help us. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

I have a newer front loader also and yes the filter is much finer than my previous one, we started cleaning the filter with each new jug of laundry detergent, since doing that we have not had the error. 
So I would try a regular schedule of cleaning, it is much easier to do when the machine is not full of water. Once a week sounds a funny are you using the proper type of detergent? The high efficiency type. Your screen may be getting plugged with fillers that some detergents use.

Comment: Can you change the mesh on the filter??

Comment: My filter looks like heat welded poly mesh . So I would say no to replacing, unless buying a new one, but a strong drain cleaner would not hurt or damage plastic parts like my washer has and may clean blockages.